# Protocol Chaining

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

Is it possible to implement protocol chaining?

For example, I'm defining a new protocol (**ProtocolA**), and I'd like to make sure that it can only be applied to objects that conform to **ProtocolB**. So something like...

```
@protocol ProtocolA <NSObject<ProtocolB>>
@end
```

**Question**

Does objective C allow this type of behaviour? If not is there a design pattern I should be aware of to achieve a similar effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using inscribed protocols (which is improper format), simply separate each individual protocol with a comma like so:

```
@protocol ProtocolA <NSObject, ProtocolB>
@end
```

It's perfectly legal. In fact, several hundred UIKit protocols are declared along these lines.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually tried this late last night, but I ran into some build errors (22 to be exact :P).

Still, I find it a bit strange that you would be able to use the syntax you've provided (i.e. NSObject is an actual class, while ProtocolB is a user defined Protocol).

I'll try and give this approach another shot later on today.

Comment: it's a little known fact that NSObject is also a protocol!  How do you think you can call +alloc?

Comment: Your right. Not sure how I missed that. Thanks for the help, your answer did the trick.